# Comparing arrays and comparing each element in both arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm new to java. Please help me out.

I want to compare Array objects, and each element in both arrays. So what should I use to check whether they are same or not: `equals`, `deepEquals` or `compareTo`?

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you storing complex objects in the array?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your problem, but maybe this will help you a little.

`Arrays.equals(array1, array2)` is used with one dimensional arrays like `int[10]`. `Arrays.deepEquals(array1,array2)` is for one or more dimensional arrays like `int[2][4]`. Chose one based on how many dimensions have arrays you want to compare.

### EDIT

Your code from comment doesn't compile but I'm starting to understand your problem. You need to know that **arrays are objects** and by default in `equals(Object obj)` method they return `this == obj`. These mean they do not compare arrays by values stored in them, but only check if reference from other object `obj` (other array) contains reference to the same array from you are comparing (`this`).

You can check it this way

```
Integer[] a1=new Integer[2];
Integer[] a2=new Integer[2];
for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
    a1[i]=i;
    a2[i]=a1[i];
}
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));//false
```

but when I change `i2` reference to point array from `i1` equals will return `true`

```
a2=a1;//now my i2 reference points array from i1
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));//true
```

To compare elements in arrays you need to iterate through array. You can write your own code to do it or use ready methods that will do it for you. Java provide such methods in class `java.util.Arrays`, but nobody stops you from using other libraries like Apache Commons -> ArrayUtils class.

Answer (score 1):

As the api says, ArrayUtils.equals does a shallow comparison. Arrays/ArrayUtils.deepEquals does a deep comparison... << this is probably the one you want (deepEquals), unless you have a reason for only wanting shallow comparison

Comment: Nowhere does the OP mention using the Apache Commons libraries.